# How to display all the data from database using json into view page in Codeigniter framework

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

**and Model page is:**

```
public function categories() {
     $this->load->model('categories_model');
    try {
        $categories = $this->categories_model->get_all();
        if (!empty($categories)) {
            $this->result = $categories;
        } else {
            throw new Exception('No data founds');
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->error = $e->getMessage();
    }
    // array data
    return $this->_prepare_return_data();
}
```

**i am a beginner to codeigniter and json . can you help me how to display the categories in view page**

Comment: Show us your model and controller page.

Comment: public function categories() {
        $result = $this->services_model->categories();
     //   var_dump($result);
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
 this is controller  and above is a model

Answer (score 0):

A basic example.

controller:

```
function categories() {
    $this->load->model('categories_model');
    $data = $this->categories_model->getCategories();
    $json = json_encode($data);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    print $json;
}
```

model:

```
function getCategories() {
    $q = $this->db->get('categories');
    return $q->result_array();
}
```

Comment: now i want to display all the categories in a view page in a list. can provide me a code to display . what to write a php code in a view page also?

Comment: Why not create an API and then just hook your website into it by calling and decoding the json?